# Execute observable in parallel while do something with each response

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a list of observables (obs$).

```
 obs$ = [ob1$, ob2$..];
```

Every time when each observable(ob$) completes,

I need to do something, ex. update a local object which are related to each observable respectively
    ob1$ = ob1(v1).do_something();
    ob1$.subscribe(e => v1.state = 'ok');

To process all the ob$ in the obs$ , I can recursively go through all ob$ and finish what I want to do  - updating v1, v2...

Now, when I think about how I can parallel this, thinking about using `forkJoin`

```
Observable.forkJoin(...obs$).subscribe( res => ..)
```

The joined response(`res`) doesn't suit my case. Am I correct?

Is there any way in Rxjs allowing me achieve what I want?

Comment: Why you think `Observable.forkJoin(...obs$).subscribe( res => ..)` is not suit in your case. ?

Comment: if the order of execution for your observables is not important to you then you might want to consider `mergeMap` operator as it executes as you get results from each inner observable. this might help: https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

Comment: Not suited because the response does not matter as long as it's not an error. So i need to know if it is not error for each one. As for order , it does not matter. That's why I am trying to go parallel

Comment: Like dee zg said: a regular mergeMap does just that. Just enqueue your x number of calls, and they will be handled whenever the responses come in. But beware: there is no true parallel execution in JS. You can be waiting for x number of api calls, but handling those responses will never truly happen in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can map each response to an `index` or whatever so you know which source Observable completed and then just use `merge`:

```
obs$ = [ob1$, ob2$, ...];
const mappedObs$ = obs$.map((ob$, index) => ob$.pipe(
  map(value => ({ index, value })),
));

merge(...mappedObs$).subscribe(({ index, value }) => {
  if (index === 42) {
    // do whatever
  }
});
```

Comment: alternatively just do the work in the `map` you added to each observable `obs$ = [obs1$.pipe(map(value => doSomething1(value))), obs2$.pipe(...), ...]; merge(obs$).subscribe()`